# Ember doesn't destroy views

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Ember is giving us some trouble. We're running a small mobile app with cordova (phonegap) and to get some structure, we decided to go with ember.

Our main problem is that ember sometimes forgets to destroy childviews, which results in overlapping views.

Has anyone had similar problems before, and how did you go about that?

Comment: Can you demonstrate with a simple fiddle???

Comment: I had a similar problem (though different), I was appending a view to multiple containers [view.appendTo(multipleConatinerSelector)], as a result multiple views were created with same Id, now while destroying the view, it was destroying only one UI view, but, not all - In my case the potential reason was [Not very sure though] view destroy() method users jQuery selector by Id, and that selects only one element but not all.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess, speculation, myth and legend without code....

But could you have forgotten to call the base function ie super() in some overridden function?